# PrimeFaces responsive is not working

Tags: jsf, primefaces, responsive-design

I want to use [PrimeFaces responsive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8FEjJ.jpg), however when I run the app in the pc all is working fine, if I resize the browser the app works as expected but if I open the app with a phone, the responsive is not working.

I am using PrimeFaces 5.3.RC1, Mojarra 2.2.0 and Glassfish 4.0

Code :

```
<h:form>
    <p:dataTable var="car" >
        <p:column headerText="Id">
            <h:outputText value="ColId" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="Year (p3)" priority="3">
            <h:outputText value="Year" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="Brand (p2)" priority="2">
            <h:outputText value="brand " />
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="Color (p4)" priority="4">
            <h:outputText value="color" />
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

[left phone, rigth pc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8FEjJ.jpg)

Comment: Did you try with the [final release](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/primefaces/primefaces/5.3/)?

Comment: And define 'not working'... Is it blowing up your phone? Try posting images what happens and what you expect. Might just be that your expectation is wrong

Comment: yes I'm using the last release PrimeFaces 5.3.

Comment: The  expect is the dataTable adapt to the size. Again, when I resize the browser in the pc depending of the size of the window, the datatable show 1 o more columns. When I open the app in the browser of the phone show all the columns.

Answer (score 2):

PrimeFaces thinks the screen is bigger than it actually is.
Tell iOS not to simulate a larger screen:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>
```

You should now get the stacked version of your datatable.

```
<html xmlns...>
<h:head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <p:dataTable ... reflow="true">
        (...)
    </p:dataTable>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use the new **reflow mode** [introduced in PrimeFaces 5.2](http://blog.primefaces.org/?p=3417) Community Edition.

[image]

Reflow mode is the best approach on mobile devices because it displays stacked columns

```
<p:dataTable var="car" reflow="true">
```

You can have a look at [the second example in the PrimeFaces' showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/responsive.xhtml).

Comment: yes, you can use reflow mode o priority mode (I am using this). When I use the showcase all is fine, the problem is when I try my app.

Comment: I've observed the same problem. It works fine when simulating it on Chrome but when I use my iPhone or the iPhone simulator the reflow does not work (on my pages). It works fine on with the PF showcase. So there is probably a slight CSS problem. I have another project where we used a PF Theme (Sentinel) and there it works okay as well.

Answer (score 1):

For the last comment ,this can help you ,if not done yet ,add

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0"/>
```

to your  and primeFaces responsive will work correctly